# Generate random melody along a given chord progression?

Tags: music-composing

I'm looking for a music software that is able to compose (random) solo melodies along a given chord progression using corresponding scales.

#### Addendum 1

The  Mac software suggested by VAlexander looks very interesting and is certainly worth mentioning for future readers. Unfortunately, in my case it's the wrong platform. I forgot to mention that I am looking for a Windows, Linux, Android or web-based application or alternatively a java library.

It does not require a full-feature music sequencer. A smart little tool would be totally sufficient.

#### Addendum 2

The tool that I've found and described in my [answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/137/generate-random-melody-along-a-given-chord-progression#answer-779) provides reasonable results, but I am still very interested in software, that addresses the same task with alternative concepts. I leave the question open therefore.

The output should be in MIDI format.

Answer (score 6):

I have found the dinosaur: [Impro-Visor](http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~keller/jazz/improvisor/). Here are my first experiences:

#### 1. Setup

- be sure to have a 32-bit Java VM at hand; to avoid undesirable interaction with my previous installation, I used a [Portable JRE](http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/java_portable)
- to get rid of the *Metal Look and Feel*, you can add a line to `impro-visor.vmoptions`:

  ```
  -Dswing.defaultlaf=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel
  ```

#### 2. Entering chord progression

- Impro-Visor has a handy quick input field, which shortcuts the whole *clicking, selecting, pressing magic correction key combination* process: 
  [image: Textual chord progression entry]
- to change the chords later, there is a source code editor:
  [image: source code editor]
- Basic settings about the accompaniment (style, instrument, volume) can be changed in the Preferences dialog: 
  [image: Preferences dialog]

#### 3. Creating Melodies

- Now we select the part, we need a melody for and launch the lick generator from the menu:
  [image: lick generator dialog]
  *(Just for reassurance: the "Abstract melody" part shown, has not to be typed in)*

  - melody and rhythm can be alternated independently
  - you can define the propability for whether a note is selected from the chord or the scale
  - pitch and intervals can be limited
  - etc.
- After some fiddling with the generator's grammar, here is a first result:
  [image: generated melody]

#### Drawbacks

- Impro-Visor mainly targets jazz improvisation, which is reflected in the available styles
- the GUI is a bit old-fashioned

At the first impression, the program looks quite useful. It offers significant opportunities, but significant learning curves as well.